# Latex: add figure to caption

Tags: latex

I would like to know how I can add a figure to the caption of a figure. I want to keep the Figure number prefix.

I'm doing the following:

```
\begin{figure*}[!ht] 
\centerline{\includegraphics{results.pdf}}
\caption{Caption, \includegraphics{arrow.pdf} caption.}
\label{fig:01}
\end{figure*}
```

But latex does not allow `\includegraphics` in the caption.

Thanks for your help.

Cheers,
ukrania

Comment: What happens if you surround the `\includegraphics` with a `\mbox{ ... }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution. It is necessary to use the `\protect` statement.

Like the following example:

```
 \begin{figure*}[!ht] 
 \centerline{\includegraphics{results.pdf}}
 \caption{Caption, \protect\includegraphics{arrow.pdf} caption.}
 \label{fig:01}
 \end{figure*}
```

Hope it helps other people with the same problem.

Cheers,
ukrania